# Can the power method give the spectral radius of a nonnegative asymmetric matrix?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I have a large sparse nonnegative asymmetric matrix $A$.
Since the matrix $A$ is nonnegative, its spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue of it.
But $A$ may have other eigenvalues being the same modulus as $\rho(A)$.

Can the power method give $\rho(A)$?

Comment: Do you need to compute the spectral radius in some specific example or do you need a rigorous proof? The set of matrices with multiple eigenvalues of the same modulus has density zero among all matrices. So for a practical computation you can just assume that there is a unique simple eigenvalue of maximal modulus.

Comment: @quarague The set of sparse matrices also has measure zero, but the OP is dealing with one.

Comment: @user1551 True, but the point I was trying to make still stands. If all you need is the spectral radius of a given matrix, just assuming there will be a unique simple eigenvalue of maximal modulus will work out fine unless you have a very specific reason why your matrix should not satisfy that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This has nothing to do with the moduli of other eigenvalues. For instance, when $A$ is not primitive, even if the moduli of other eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly smaller than $\rho(A)$, the power method still doesn't always converge. For an illustrative example, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&2\\ 1&0},\ x_0=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}.
$$
Using the power method, the iterates will oscillate between $x_0$ and $x_1=(\frac23,\frac13)^T$ and none of them is an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Wow. What an example. Then is there any way, as simple as possible, to get the spectral radius?

Comment: @Eli4ph I don't know any such method. You may do a web search for "power method for non-primitive matrices" or the like to see if there are viable solutions. The authors of [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8405/da8ccbc2618ceff3e8c0463197f49c73eab9.pdf) for instance have proposed an algorithm, which they claim is more robust.